# Поясните фрагмент кода

Tags: haskell

```
 hendl <- openFile fileName ReadMode
 loadFacts <- hGetContents hendl
 qs <- return (table (read loadFacts))
 run qs 
 hClose hendl
```

вот фрагмент функции, поясните, пожалуйста, что здесь делает read и return

Если что, вот определения rub и table

```
 run::Table -> IO ()
 table::Facts->Table
```

[[@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz) у меня еще вопрос по функции read - мы ей передаем указатель на файл, и она как она считывает (функция table имеет вид

```
table::Facts->Table, где 
type Fact = (String,[(String,Bool)]) 
type Facts = [Fact] ) а входной файл имеет вид

[("aa1",
      [("bb", True), 
      ("cc", False),]), 
("aa2", 
      [("bb", True), 
      ("cc", True),])]
```

И как происходит чтение? Построчно или каждый кортеж считывает?

Comment: read не читает никакого файла. У неё на входе строка `read :: Read a => String -> a`, результат -- типа `a`, в Вашем случае Facts. Чтение файла у Вас -- hGetContents. Вы можете `read` и `show` переопределить для своего типа данных (насчёт псевдонимов `type` -- не помню, возможно и нет). Так что считывает сразу всё. Кстати, у Вас там запятых не лишку? (перед кв. скобками). Хотя, как идёт чтение файла с учётом ленивости -- не знаю.

Comment: а какая строка подается read на вход (имею ввиду какая строка входного файла) ?  или loadFacts сразу принимает вид  [ (String, [(String,Bool)] ) ] ?

Comment: А какая у неё в параметрах? `loadFacts`, которая содержимое (всё -- hGetContents) файла fileName. ("сразу" -- это в процессе работы, ленивость не забывайте) `hGetContents :: Handle -> IO String`. А loadFacts имеет тип String. Парсинг и преобразование в значение типа Facts осуществляет read.

Comment: спс, а из-за ленивости оно обрабатывается не на лету ? а как же тогда строиться таблица ?по мере чтения ?

Comment: В общем случае именно "на лету", по мере надобности.И чтение из файла (по крайней мере логически) происходит по мере надобности таблицы. Правда тут вмешивается логика read, который может принуждать читать всё (в момент, когда нужен любой элемент Facts). Если вам нужно построение раньше необходимого по логике (например по причине эффективности, но тут нужен анализ кода и/или профилирование) -- принуждайте. Функции `seq`, `$!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. run выполняет вычисление, содержащееся в переменной gs.
2. return (тип a -> m a) -- создаёт это вычисление. В принципе он тут вроде и не нужен, т.е. (если я не путаю) две строки

   qs <- return (table (read loadFacts))  
   run qs

эквивалентны

```
run (table (read loadFacts))
```

, где read имеет тип String -> Facts 
Другой вариант записи

```
let gs = table (read loadFacts))
run gs
```

Для ясности можете переписать это без do-нотаций, в терминах комбинаторов `>==` и `return`